# SelectParameter fails using ? or @

Tags: sql, asp.net, ms-access

Problem with the 3rd SelectParameter not getting recognized in the SQL statement: `[UsersDataTbl.UID] NOT IN (SELECT UID FROM [EnrollmentsTbl] WHERE ClassName = ?) AND Completed = True` I have used `@ClassName` as well and get same error: "No value given for one or more required parameters."

If I replace the ? with 'actual class name', the results are as desired.

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="ClassName" DataValueField="ClassName">
</asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource4" DataTextField="Battallion" 
    DataValueField="Battallion" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource5" DataTextField="Shift" 
    DataValueField="Shift" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;

<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataFile="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AccessSubSiteString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [UsersDataTbl.StudentID], [UsersDataTbl.UserName], 
    [UsersDataTbl.LastName], [UsersDataTbl.FirstName], [UsersDataTbl.Affiliation], [UsersDataCareerTbl.Battallion], [UsersDataCareerTbl.Shift], [UsersDataTbl.UID], [ALSProviders.ALS] 
    FROM ([UsersDataTbl] INNER JOIN [UsersDataCareerTbl] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = UsersDataCareerTbl.UID)) LEFT JOIN [ALSProviders] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = ALSProviders.UID)
    WHERE [UsersDataTbl.Career] = True AND [UsersDataTbl.Active] = True AND (UsersDataCareerTbl.Battallion = ?) AND (UsersDataCareerTbl.Shift = ?) 
    AND ([UsersDataTbl.UID] NOT IN (SELECT UID FROM [EnrollmentsTbl] WHERE ClassName = ?) AND Completed = True)
    ORDER BY [UsersDataTbl.LastName]">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList3" Name="Battallion" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList4" Name="Shift" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" /> 
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="ClassName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />           
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: So do you have an object with ID = "DropDownList1"?

Comment: Yes and the ddl is populating with the class names.

Comment: Is there a default selected value?

Comment: Try to change this part:

Comment: no since it populated from the DB, however 'Battallion' and 'Shift' parameters are working

Comment: That is why it is failing because it does not have a default value.

Comment: but the other 2 parameters don't have defaults and they are populating the SQL fine - If I set a default it will always be the default value if what you are saying is true... it does a post back after the ddl is selected.

Comment: I don't know, but the sub query could be the problem.
Try something like this (remenber to change the parameters order now).
`...LEFT JOIN [ALSProviders] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = ALSProviders.UID)
 LEFT JOIN [EnrollmentsTbl] ON [UsersDataTbl.UID] = [EnrollmentsTbl.UID] AND ClassName = ?
    WHERE [UsersDataTbl.Career] = True AND [UsersDataTbl.Active] = True AND (UsersDataCareerTbl.Battallion = ?) AND (UsersDataCareerTbl.Shift = ?) 
    AND [EnrollmentsTbl.UID] IS NOT NULL AND Completed = True)
    ORDER BY [UsersDataTbl.LastName]`

Comment: can't use `[EnrollmentsTbl.UID] IS NOT NULL` since there are multiple class names and the same UID is used for each class inserted.

Comment: updated question to show DDL code

Comment: Yes you do! The result query is the same. Where you use a subquery NOT IN, I use a LEFT JOIN. The LEFT will bring all results but the [EnrollmentsTbl.UID] will be NULL for those registers that NOT IN in table. Thats the reason for I use IS NOT NULL (the result must be the same). Try it, just to know if the subquery is the problem.

Comment: ok tried your example, error was: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(UsersDataTbl.UID = ALSProviders.UID) 
       LEFT JOIN [EnrollmentsTbl] ON [UsersDataTbl.UID] = [EnrollmentsTbl.UID] AND ClassName = ?'.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the tables here to test.., here we are.. try it know
    FROM ([UsersDataTbl] 
 INNER JOIN [UsersDataCareerTbl] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = UsersDataCareerTbl.UID)) 
 LEFT JOIN [ALSProviders] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = ALSProviders.UID)
 LEFT JOIN [EnrollmentsTbl] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = EnrollmentsTbl.UID AND ClassName = ?)
    WHERE [UsersDataTbl.Career] = True AND [UsersDataTbl.Active] = True AND (UsersDataCareerTbl.Battallion = ?) AND (UsersDataCareerTbl.Shift = ?) 
    AND (EnrollmentsTbl.UID IS NULL AND Completed = True)
    ORDER BY [UsersDataTbl.LastName]

Comment: error still: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(UsersDataTbl.UID = ALSProviders.UID) LEFT JOIN [EnrollmentsTbl] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = EnrollmentsTbl.UID AND ClassName = '?')'.  Your syntax looks funny at 'AND ClassName = ?) : seems this need a 'WHERE' And not 'AND'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Rafael for the direction, adding the additional JOIN seemed to fix it. Still needed the `IS NULL`. here is the resolution:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataFile="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AccessSubSiteString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [UsersDataTbl.StudentID], [UsersDataTbl.UserName], [UsersDataTbl.LastName], [UsersDataTbl.FirstName], [UsersDataTbl.Affiliation], [UsersDataCareerTbl.Battallion], [UsersDataCareerTbl.Shift], [UsersDataTbl.UID], [ALSProviders.ALS] 
    FROM (([UsersDataTbl] INNER JOIN [UsersDataCareerTbl] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = UsersDataCareerTbl.UID)) 
    LEFT JOIN [ALSProviders] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = ALSProviders.UID)) 
    LEFT JOIN [EnrollmentsTbl] ON (UsersDataTbl.UID = EnrollmentsTbl.UID AND ClassName = ?) 
    WHERE [UsersDataCareerTbl.Battallion] = ?  
    AND [UsersDataCareerTbl.Shift] = ?  
    AND [EnrollmentsTbl.UID] IS NULL 
    ORDER BY [UsersDataTbl.LastName]">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList3" Name="Battallion" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList4" Name="Shift" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" /> 
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="ClassName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />           
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```